R tinytex PATH-Variable
When I install tinytex-Package and then TinyTeX like:
install.packages("tinytex")
library(tinytex)
install_tinytex(add_path = TRUE)

There is a PATH-Variable created, but e. g. TexMaker seems to not find it.

So it works fine in R, but you are having difficulty using an external program? Have you tried restarting your computer so that TexMaker can inherit the updated PATH variable?
